Some requests work and others don’t on postman
I'm a very new geek trying to build an application using NodeJs and ExpressJs. I'm testing the backend with postman. some of the requests work perfectly but others don’t, I've been getting cannot get the url message, 404 not found for hours now, and as I mentioned other routes work very good.
Everything seems ok Server side, type content is JSON, I've checked the code multiple times and I can’t see the error. any ideas please? Thank you .
The server:

Postman response:

The model:
module.exports = (_db) => {
  db = _db;
  return SearchModel;
};
class SearchModel {
  //Get a product by name
  static getProductByName(productName) {
    return db
      .query('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE productName = ?', [
        productName
      ])
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });
  }
  // Get products by gender
  static getProductByGender(gender) {
    return db
      .query('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE gender = ?', [gender])
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      });
  }
  // Get products by brand
  static getProductByBrand(brand) {
    return db
      .query('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE brand=?', [brand])
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      });
  }
  // Get products by mouvement
  static getProductByMouvement(mouvement) {
    return db
      .query('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE mouvement=?', [mouvement])
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      });
  }
}

The route:
  // Get a product by name
  module.exports = (app, db) => {
  const searchModel = require('../models/SearchModel')(db);

  // Route pour afficher un produit par son nom
  app.get('/api/v1/Search/name', async (req, res) => {
    const productByName = await searchModel.getProductByName(
      req.body.productName,
    );

    if (productByName.code) {
      res.json({ status: 500, msg: 'Server Error!' });
    } else if (!productByName) {
      res.json({ status: 404, msg: 'Product not found!' });
    } else {
      res.json({ status: 200, result: productByName, msg: 'Voilà!' });
    }
  });
};


the SQL query "CELECT..." , should be "SELECT...", no?

thank you, i did notice , but still the same after correcting

I think what you should do is try to simplify your route, for testing. just like a simple response. find something stable to build off of.

app.get('/api/v1/search/name', ... ) change 'Search' to 'search' ( lower case letter ) . for consistency at least. any url should be lower case. also, in your postman request, use x-www-form-urlencoded option. maybe that will help stabilize things

Thank you so much ! I did use lower case letters then changed to upper case, nothing works. Just tried the x-www-form-urlencoded, not working eather

Where are you importing the route module? Show that code.

the problem for me was that I forgot to add the searchRoute to the db in the server.js! 2days for that , but everything working well now.
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
          res.json({ status: 200  });
        });
        userRoute(app, db);
        productRoute(app, db);
        orderRoute(app, db);
        authRoute(app, db);
        searchRoute(app, db);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

Thanks for your answers, They made me do some research and learn a few things

Are you sure that in GET request params are in body?
This is the correct way:
app.get('/path', (req, res) => {
  const productName= req.query.productName;

  // Do something with the query parameters
  console.log(productName);
  
  res.send('Query parameters received');
});

And since the product is not found, you return 404 which means page not found as far as PostMan shows.

Thank you @IT goldman! I tried your method but unfortunately I still have the same problem, postman cannot get the url

you can try in browser without postman and see if works. test a link similar to this one: http://localhost:9000/api/v1/Search/name?productName=hello

req.body in GET and DELETE request is not valid, you should use params or queries instead. Like:
app.get('/api/v1/Search/:name', async (req, res) => {
  const name = req.params.name
  console.log(name) //    try /api/v1/Search/abc => name = 'abc'
})
// or
app.get('/api/v1/Search', async (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name
  console.log(name) //    try /api/v1/Search/?name=abc => name = 'abc'
})

